# Set Value of lightning-combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components

How would I set the value in the following lightning-combobox?  I was using this to set a variable but I the console.log really does not give me what I'm looking for.  When I run the following...

let inp = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id="ownerfilter"]');
console.log('2 here is the value of the inp ' + inp);

I get  [object NodeList]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} } in the console.

```
<lightning-combobox
            lwc:ref="myDiv"
                data-id="ownerfilter"
                name="ownerfilter"
                label="Select Owner" 
                options={ownerChoices}
                placeholder="Select Owner"
                value={value}
                onchange={ownerfilterchange}
                class="FilterStyle">
            </lightning-combobox>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querySelectorAll returns an Array-like object called a NodeList. From there the `+` operator on strings returns the value of `toString()`, which is why you see `[object NodeList]` as part of the output.

Instead:

```
console.log(this.template.querySelector('[data-id="ownerfilter"]').value);
```

or:

```
console.log(this.refs.myDiv.value);
```

You should get out of the habit of using `+` in console.log. Use the comma operator instead to see interactive values:

```
console.log('this is the value:', this.refs.myDiv.value);
```